# How do I prevent orphaned `sshd` processes on the server end?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, unix, sshd

I have a number of processes on client machines that `ssh` to server machines and do things. Sometimes those client processes end unexpectedly for whatever reason. This always leaves an `sshd` process running on the server end. I want that process to die.

Note that this is different than disconnecting an *idle* process. An idle process is one where no *user* data is flowing. An unused terminal window running ssh, for instance, is idle but not disconnected. This is not a case I want to kill--I want merely *idle* connections to stay alive.

A *disconnected* process is one where the client end no longer has the socket open.

The server end could theoretically detect this by `ssh`/`sshd` jointly using heartbeats in a side band. If either one fails to hear the other's heartbeats, it could kill itself. But I can't find an option that does that. (There are many options that sound like they do that, but don't.)

Obviously it is also possible to periodically "reap" the orphaned `sshd`s on the server end. I'd want to avoid that too. For any reap period, I could have many orphaned connections (in a parallel processing situation, for instance). Also, I would have to through some gyrations to prevent myself from killing in-use `sshd` instances, if there's even a way for me to detect that.

How can I make `sshd` detect disconnected clients and kill itself?

Comment: There is a distinction between "client socket is closed" (in which case the client OS will send a TCP RST as soon as the server tries to send _any_ data) and "client is gone" (in which case the server will reach a TCP retransmission timeout several minutes after trying to send any data).

Comment: OK. Either version of "the socket is not open" could happen and I'd like the server end to kill the `sshd` process in either case. Granted that it may take a few minutes for the server to realize this in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for `sshd_config` will tell you that setting `ClientAliveCountMax` & `ClientAliveInterval` should do as you wish.

`ClientAliveCountMax` is defaulted to 3, meaning you just need to set `ClientAliveInterval` to a suitable size.

Comment: +1. True. The issue in the question is exactly what `ClientAlive*` are for. [Sometimes people misinterpret these settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/585862/108618).

Comment: [This question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-d) is pretty clear that this are about *idleness* not *disconnectivity*. And in practice, this doesn't seem to work. One of my servers has `ClientAliveInterval 300` and `ClientAliveCountMax 3` and keeps disconnected instances around for weeks at a time.

Comment: More googling indicates that you are right, this is how that's supposed to work. I guess I now need to figure out why it isn't on any machine I touch....

Comment: After some experiments, I got this working...but the logic for `CountMax` seems to be reversed. The server *only* terminates a missing client if `ClientAliveCountMax` is set to 0. If I set the `Interval` to 300 and the `CountMax` to 3, nothing happens after 15 minutes. If I set `CountMax` to 0, the server correctly terminates after 5 minutes.